# Не получается вызвать функцию отображения в главном модуле из вызываемого модуля

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

есть главный модуль get.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Test(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test):
        Test.setObjectName("Test")
        Test.resize(805, 352)
        Test.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 301))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        Test.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Test)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 805, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu.setObjectName("menuMenu")
        self.menuOption = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOption.setObjectName("menuOption")
        Test.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionTesting = QtWidgets.QAction(Test)
        self.actionTesting.setObjectName("actionTesting")
        self.menuOption.addAction(self.actionTesting)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOption.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(Test,'')
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test)

         #Привязка действий к пунктам меню
        self.actionTesting.triggered.connect(self.Test)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test,TT):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test.setWindowTitle(_translate("Test", "Test")) #Вот тут выдается ошибка,но если просто закомментить, то пропадает заголовок окна
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("Test",TT))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("Test", "Menu"))
        self.menuOption.setTitle(_translate("Test", "Option"))
        self.actionTesting.setText(_translate("Test", "Testing"))

    def Test(self):
        import test1
        c=1
        while c<30:
           test1.testXX(c)
           c=c+1

        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Test = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Test()
    ui.setupUi(Test)
    Test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

и есть вызываемый модуль test1.py

```
def testXX(a):

    while a < 30:
        b=str(a)
        from get import Ui_Test
        Ui_Test.retranslateUi(Ui_Test,"Test", b)
        a=a+1
        return a,b
    else:
        pass
   return a,b
```

При вызове Ui_Test.retranslateUi(Ui_Test,"Test", b) идет ошибка, и я не понимаю причин. Очевидно, что данные передаются все и полностью.

Цель - выводить в главное окно (plainTextEdit) значения от 1 до 30 из функции TestXX и так, чтобы они не затирали предыдущие, а добавлялись ниже ранее выведенных

текст ошибки
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmitriy.alekseev\Desktop\PY\Новая попытка\get.py", line 119, in Test
    test1.testXX(c)
  File "C:\Users\dmitriy.alekseev\Desktop\PY\Новая попытка\test1.py", line 5, in testXX
    Ui_Test.retranslateUi(Ui_Test,"Test", b)
  File "C:\Users\dmitriy.alekseev\Desktop\PY\Новая попытка\get.py", line 48, in retranslateUi
    self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("Test",TT))
AttributeError: type object 'Ui_Test' has no attribute 'plainTextEdit'

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: добавил текст ошбки

Answer (score 0):

С именами полная чехарда. Название - Test, класс - Test, метод - Test )

Пробуй пример:

get.py

```
import test1                                                        # +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Test(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test):
        Test.setObjectName("Test")
        Test.resize(805, 352)
        Test.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 301))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        Test.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Test)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 805, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu.setObjectName("menuMenu")
        self.menuOption = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOption.setObjectName("menuOption")
        Test.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionTesting = QtWidgets.QAction(Test)
        self.actionTesting.setObjectName("actionTesting")
        self.menuOption.addAction(self.actionTesting)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOption.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(Test,'')
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test)

        #Привязка действий к пунктам меню
        #self.actionTesting.triggered.connect(self.Test)                   # ---
        self.actionTesting.triggered.connect(self.test_Ui)                 # +++

    def retranslateUi(self, Test, TT):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test.setWindowTitle("Test")      
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("plainTextEdit", TT))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("Test", "Menu"))
        self.menuOption.setTitle(_translate("Test", "Option"))
        self.actionTesting.setText(_translate("Test", "Testing"))

    # +++ test_Ui       
    def test_Ui(self):
        #import test1
        c = 1
        while c < 30:
           a, b = test1.testXX(c, Test, self)                              # +++
           c=c+1
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Test = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Test()
    ui.setupUi(Test) 
    Test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

test1.py

```
def testXX(a, Test, self):     # +++

    while a < 30:
        b = str(a)
        from get import Ui_Test
        #Ui_Test.retranslateUi(Ui_Test,"Test", b)  # ---
        Ui_Test.retranslateUi(self, Test, b)       # +++
        a = a + 1
        return a, b
    else:
        pass
    return a, b
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]